# First app page not loading correctly at start, only when app is downloaded from the windows store

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store

I've recently published a windows 8.1 universal app on the Windows Store. When I download it from the store on 8.1 devices, the first page of the app doesn't load correctly, some controls miss. On Windows 10 device, it works well.

If I put the app in the background and then recall it, the page loads correctly.
During the development, I've tested the app on several smartphones and I've never meet this problem.

Has someone met this issue?

1. [In this capture, all controls are loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSN7v.png)
2. [In this one, the checkbox is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjvyb.png)

I'm using the MVVM pattern without external package and I use the control Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls.Popup for displaying error messages.

Comment: *app doesn't load correctly, some controls miss.* that's too vague, add a more detailed explanation on what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved**, it was a custom control who makes this bug. I use it on each of my pages and it works well. But when the app downloaded from the store starts, it perturbs the loading of the first page of the application.